# Strange “Devices” section in iOS Wi-Fi Settings

Tags: ios, wifi, settings

Has anyone ever seen this ‘Devices’ section in the Wi-Fi Settings page?

It very strange, it's my first time I've seen this. Even more, when I tried to connect to this SSID, iOS pops up a dialog which says "*x* is not connected to the Internet; Are you sure you want to use this network?"

What is this? How was this achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen when (for example) a MacBook computer was used to create it's own Wi-Fi network.

The pop-up you see indicates that after you connect to this SSID you won't have internet access.

Such networks are called Ad-Hoc networks (more info: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network)) .